# Run from the command line of a job

Tags: sql-server

I have to find the dynamic REPL-LogReader each night and stop it otherwise when I go to drop the subscriptions it says there can only be one log reader. Which makes sense. All of this needs to be in a job command line on a SQL Server 2016.

Is there anything wrong with running this in the command line of a job?

```
DECLARE @ReplLogReader nvarchar(25)
SELECT top(1) @ReplLogReader = name from msdb.dbo.sysjobs 
WHERE category_id IN (SELECT category_id FROM msdb.dbo.syscategories WHERE name = 'REPL-LogReader') 

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_Stop_job @job_name =@replLogReader
GO

-- Dropping the transactional articles:
USE [CrazyDB]
exec sp_replflush
exec sp_dropsubscription @publication = N'LCrazyhost, @article = N'CheckLink_Data', @subscriber = N'all', @destination_db = N'all'.....
(MORE code... )
```

There is more but if it can get the the **USE [CrazyDB]** to drop the subscriptions I'm fine with that

Comment: Why are you dropping the subscriptions every night?

Comment: @Tara We do a backsync of a semi production server. The subscription and replication get rebuilt each night. The replLogReader changes names because it is a brand new one after the process

Comment: But why? Why drop and then set it up again? The bigger the database gets, the more prohibitive that'll be. Why not backup/restore or just keep replication in place?

Comment: I'll have to figure that out once I get more knowledge about how they built it. I'm 2 Weeks here at this company. There's a lot more going on with  Back syncing other than restore, replication... (15 steps, including using SSIS packages etc..) .For now, I'm looking at preventing the error it throws when  trying to drop the subscriptions and want to make sure that step 1 includes that before it drops subscriptions.

Comment: and @TaraKizer, I know you're the replication guru. I listen to you, Erik and Brent on the podcasts and they defer those questions to you ;-). I'm sure I'll circle back around to you for a better fix for why they drop and not something else.

Answer (score 0):

The sql inside the job command line works perfectly. After stopping the REPL-LogReader, it continued on to the flush and dropping of subscriptions and finished up all 15 steps.